# Triggering ng-style variable change

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive to change the background-color of my navbar on the homepage.

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window,$location) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {       
        console.log(this.pageYOffset);   
        if (this.pageYOffset > 0) {
          scope.backgroundCol = "black";
        } else {
          scope.backgroundCol = "transparent";
        }
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };
});
```

In the index.html page, I added the binding to the `backgroundCol` variable.

```
<nav id="mainNav" ng-controller="MainController" ng-style="{'background': backgroundCol}" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

And in my home.html (binded through a `ng-view`), I added the binding to the scroll directive :

```
<div class="container fill" scroll>
```

The directive is registered, and I can see the offset, but I can't manage to change my navbar's color.

Comment: Not really sure, but maybe switching from `"black"` to `'black'`?

Comment: Is your `<nav id="mainNav">` element part of the `scope`? Because `backgroundCol` is defined inside the scope `<div class="container">` scope.

Comment: You are right, that's not the same scope. How can I make it be the same? Do I have to use the rootscope?